# the link between fcntl and sockets

Tags: c

I have read about socket, connecting, fcntl, buffers, etc.
But I don't know what the link between the sockets and the fcntl function is.
I only know that sockets are used to make a connection, and fcntl is used to control open files. I don't know how fcntl is used to control files and how it is different from the fopen, fwrite, fclose functions.
So could anyone help with this, because I am stuck.

Comment: You seem to be saying that you have read some general descriptive information about these functions.  Don't you think that reading their actual *documentation* might give you a better understanding?  Googling for `fcntl` gives me four copies of `fcntl()`'s manual page among the top five hits, and one copy of the manual page for `fcntl.h`, which is perhaps an even greater treasure.

Comment: Yeah, I have done that, but I make nothing from that info.

Comment: Then I doubt we can offer an answer that would help.  For us even to try, you need to narrow your question substantially.  It would be best to base it on actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fcntl` system call is used to perform operations on an open file descriptor - getting or setting the file descriptor flags (e.g. changing O_APPEND or O_NONBLOCK status flags).

`int fcntl(int fd, int cmd, ... /* arg */ );`

An open socket will be referenced by a file descriptor (sockFd in this case):

`sockFd = socket (PF_LOCAL, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);`

An example - to make the socket non-blocking, use `fcntl` to change the status of the socket's file descriptor. * Note simplified code:*

`int flags = fcntl(sockFd, F_GETFL, 0);   /* get socket's flags */
 flags |= O_NONBLOCK;  /* Add O_NONBLOCK status to socket descriptor's flags */
 status = fcntl(sockFd, F_SETFL, flags); /* Apply the new flags to the socket */`

Comment: Thanks for your reaction

Answer (score 0):

fcntl() is used to control a file descriptor (not specifically a file).
open() may be used to obtain a file descriptor associated with a file. Also for example socket() and pipe() calls return a file descriptor. Those file descriptors may be later used with fcntl().
So the connection is: the file descriptor obtained from a socket() call may be used as the argument to fcntl() function.
File descriptors and associated functions are part of the POSIX standard.

You mentioned fopen().
fopen() returns a FILE pointer. In simple words, FILE pointer is something build *above* file descriptor (on most *unix systems, but this is not necessary and may not be true). For example, FILE pointer may have some buffering options: written bytes are stored in a buffer and then flushed on a newline (this behavior may be modified using setvbuf()) or manually by a fflush() call.
You may use fileno() to get the file descriptor associated with the FILE* pointer. And then use this file descriptor with the fcntl() call. ( FILE* pointer is not necessary associated with a file either, for example it may be associated with a memory buffer, see fmemopen() function. )
fopen(), fwrite(), fclose() are part of the C standard.